# Deploying artifacts in nexus from maven gives error "Return code is: 401"?

Tags: maven, nexus

I am getting 401 error while deploying in nexus. I does not make any changes to the installed nexus. Nexus is running on `localhost:8080/nexus` and i am able to login with default user/password. When i am running `mvn deploy` i am getting this error.

Here is my POM.

```
 <groupId>testproject</groupId>
 <artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>testproject</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
 <distributionManagement>
  <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
       <id>snapshots</id>
       <url>http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
 .........
</dependencies>
```

and ~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Exception:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-           deploy) on project testproject: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact testproject:testproject:jar:1.0-20131213.150615-1 from/to snapshots (http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots): Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/testproject/testproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testproject-1.0-20131213.150615-1.jar. 
Return code is: 401 -> [Help 1]
```

Please help me.

Comment: `Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/testproject/testproject/1.0-SNAPSHOT/testproject-1.0-20131213.150615-1.jar.` Does the file exist?

Comment: no, Its not uploaded to the nexus. But exists in my local target directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's working now. Need to edit `${MVN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml` instead of `/home/{user}/.m2/settings.xml`

Comment: That indicates that you were running the maven execution as a different user thant "user". You should not need to do that.

Comment: @Gangaraju men ur awesome u saved my day but i cant get why /home/user/.m2/settings.xml dosent work

Comment: Thanks @AdnenChouibi,@HaithemRihane. I did not spend much time on it  as it solves my problem. My observation was it's working if we install maven using `apt-get install` and it's not working if we unzip the maven tar and exported in $PATH.

Comment: I am getting 413 error and i have checked that settings.xml files under /home/user is being used. Any clue what could be going wrong here. It is happening when i am trying to upload a jar using standalone project using maven command line

Comment: to find {MVN_HOME} - `mvn --version`

Answer (score 3):

HTTP 401 is the status code for "unauthorized", which implies that your `deployment` user isn't authorized to upload artifacts to that particular repository in Nexus. Log in to Nexus and give the `deployment` user the role(s) required to to change that snapshot repo.

Answer (score 1):

> I was missing the`<servers>` tag on my `.m2/settings.xml` on 
>   Gitlab-ci + MAVEN + Jfrog Artifactory:

**My gitlab-ci.yxml**

```
Artifactory_deploy:
  stage: install
  only:
    - desarrollo
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to Artifactory"
    - cd $CLONE_DIR
    - mvn -X deploy
```

**My .m2/settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${ARTIFACTORY_USER}</username>
      <password>${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${ARTIFACTORY_USER}</username>
      <password>${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>develop</id>
      <properties>
        <artifactory.ip>${ARTIFACTORY_IP}</artifactory.ip>
        <artifactory.port>${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}</artifactory.port>
      </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>THISWASMYENCRYPTEDPASSWORD</password>
          <url>http://${ARTIFACTORY_IP}:${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>THISWASMYENCRYPTEDPASSWORD</password>
          <url>http://${ARTIFACTORY_IP}:${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <url>http://${ARTIFACTORY_IP}:${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <username>admin</username>
          <password>password</password>
          <url>http://${ARTIFACTORY_IP}:${ARTIFACTORY_PORT}/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
<activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>develop</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>


<servers>
    <server>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>releases</id>
        <username>deployment</username>
        <password>deployment123</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Answer (score 1):

The user that you use for snapshot deployments needs a role with these privileges:

- nx-repository-view-maven2-maven-snapshots-read
- nx-repository-view-maven2-maven-snapshots-edit
- nx-repository-view-maven2-maven-snapshots-add